# segmented piece wise linear regression problem?

Tags: regression, piecewise-linear

I want to get a piecewise linear regression model with the function "segmented".

```
> daten<-read.csv("/Users/rn/Desktop/daten.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",")
> lm1<-lm(kwh~at, data = daten)
> seg <- segmented(lm1, seg.Z=~at, psi = list(at = c(0, 25)))
```

I get the error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = kwh ~ at + U1.at + U2.at + psi1.at +  : 
invalid type (list) for variable 'at'
```

The dataset are 856 values, daily temperature (at) and heating load (kwh)

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: difficult to help you without a reproducible example! Can you provide one? is the at variable continuous or factor?